# Python dictionary is not saving to data - Pickle

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

So I am making a game with a leaderboard, so, but it still resets every time. This is my code:

```
config_dictionary[url] = short
with open('config.dictionary', 'wb') as config_dictionary_file:
  pickle.dump(config_dictionary, config_dictionary_file)
  print(config_dictionary)
```

When I use a dictionary to test `test_dictionary['thing one'] = 'thing two'` it works fine to add it. But every time I put it into the code above, it will just reset. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting in different answers for each one. If you are testing, you should put in different things, instead of the same one. It doesn't work for me if I put in the same answers.

Answer (score 0):

try saving your score by writing in to txt file rather than using a pickle as it is a much more advanced way. With something like this:

```
with open("score.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(score)
```

And at the beginning of you game just load last saved score with something like this:

```
try:
    with open("score.txt", "r") as file:
        score = int(file.readline())
except Exception:
    score = 0
```

Comment: I hope this will help if you have any questions or need further assistance let me know.